# Webpage update without refresh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh, partial-page-refresh

I'm playing around with making a page update without refreshing and I've read some tutorials and came up with the following code. However it doesn't seem to be working. When you press the button, nothing seems to happen.

Index.php code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

        <script>
                function updateShouts()
                {                
                    $('#refresh').load('update.php');
                    alert('it works!'); uncomment this to know if your script works
                } 
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="refresh">
            <?php
            include('update.php');
            ?>
            <button onclick="updateShouts()">Try it</button>

        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

update.php code

```
<?php
print strftime('%c');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your jquery link separately from your other script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
        function updateShouts()
        {                
            $('#refresh').load('update.php');
            //alert('it works!'); uncomment this to know if your script works
        } 
</script>
```

or you can use an updated online jquery library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

    <script>
        function updateShouts()
        {                
            $('#refresh').load('update.php');
            //alert('it works!'); uncomment this to know if your script works
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean IoQ?

Comment: notice your script header? <script src="jquery.js"> ? Just remove the src and separate this like the example above.

Comment: Just tried that and it's still not working. I uncommented the alert popup and it doesn't show suggesting it doesn't fire. Updated question to show new code

Comment: it doesnt work because of the syntax error.. remove also the text 'uncomment this to know if your script works' or replace your jquery link with src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js'